# cmake operation file of STRINGS breaches intuition

Tags: c++, c, cmake

When I write CMakeLists.txt for learning CMake. I meet something that is opposite of what I think it should be.

---

Here are contents of including files.

- CMakeLists.txt

```
file(STRINGS "main.cpp" set LENGTH_MAXIMUM 30 LENGTH_MINIMUM 5 LIMIT_COUNT 6 LIMIT_INPUT 31 LIMIT_OUTPUT 32 ENCODING UTF-8)
#  REGEX [=[[a]+]=] NEWLINE_CONSUME NO_HEX_CONVERSION
message(${set})
foreach(i ${set})
    string(LENGTH "${i}" res)
    message(${res})
endforeach()
```

- **main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

- **1.txt**

```
Hello, world!
This is a test file.
It has three lines of text.
```

---

I note that in `main.cpp` the first two lines only contain 29 characters. But if I need include them I have to set `LIMIT_INPUT` 31, that is 29+2. And if I want the same thing happening I also need set `LIMIT_OUTPUT` 32, 1 more than 31 and 3 more than 29.

```
file(STRINGS "main.cpp" set LENGTH_MAXIMUM 30 LENGTH_MINIMUM 5 LIMIT_COUNT 6 LIMIT_INPUT 31 LIMIT_OUTPUT 32 ENCODING UTF-8)
```

OUTPUT is:

```
[cmake] #include <iostream>int main()
[cmake] 19
[cmake] 10
```

---

Same thing happens in 1.txt

if I write in CMakeLists.txt like following:

```
file(STRINGS 1.txt collect LIMIT_INPUT 16 LIMIT_OUTPUT 17)
message("${collect}")
string(LENGTH "${collect}" res)
message(${res})
```

In this condition variable `collect` only has two elements of list as `Hello, world!` and `T`. Counting as 14, but `LIMIT_INPUT` also needs 2 more than 14, which is 16. `LIMIT_OUTPUT` even 1 more than `LIMIT_INPUT`.

---

I wonder why `LIMIT_INPUT` is not equal to the counting sum. And `LIMIT_OUTPUT` also follows.

If `LIMIT_INPUT` does need more than sum, why `LIMIT_OUTPUT` needs more than `LIMIT_INPUT` yet.

They should look same. Aren't they?

Comment: A line roughly consists of visible characters with spaces + two invisible symbols \r\n (line feed and new line).

Comment: Your suggestion indeed reminds me. Thanks a lot. I have my vscode newline_style CRLF instead of unix-style LF.